# Shift of the null half-reaction potential

Tags: electrochemistry, redox

If we change the null half-potential, would it change half-potentials of other half-cell reactions by the same amount, so that voltages of net reactions stay the same?

Comment: Yes, you should be right: changing the standard electrode changes the half-cell potentials but the galvanic cell potentials (resulting from a pair of electrodes) stay the same.